# SocialEngineeringToolkit (SET) IOError when starting up

Tags: python, linux, github, vmware-player

I am setting up [SET](https://www.trustedsec.com/social-engineer-toolkit/) with Tails OS as described in their web site. Tried installing and executing SET from two different machines with the same results. One is running Tails using a virtual machine, the other boots up from USB.

My first attempt, SET reports errors of missing dependencies, specifically pythonopenssl, which I then installed.

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Apparently all dependencies are now installed, at least no further  "missing dependencies" are reported when starting up the program.

Regardless, even With openSSL installed, a new error is reported.

```
File "python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
./setoolkit IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I will provide you with the full callstack if you need it. The first line of the callstack is

```
python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py, line 258, in _bootstrap
self.run()...
```

Even tried to update the SETookit, with its own options, the application  throws the same error.

Is this error related to my connection and how is set up?

Is there a way to diagnose the toolkit before running it? I meant like validating dependencies.

Is it that using SET in Tails is very hard to setup? A better recommendation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you think it would make sense trying by updating python?

Answer (score 0):

Tails relies on TCP/IP for communication.

Any attempt to send packages of other kind, like icmp through ping, will fail. Haven't found any details if this is possible to set up in Tails, but I suspect if it was possible it will affect OS security (any thoughts??).

With regular linux distros, like debia, slack or Ubuntu, this problem won't appear anymore.